# Unconfirmed bitcoin transaction 5 hours

Tags: transactions

Its been 5 hours since I did a transaction of $ 64 and it has not been confirmed
I checked it says unspent 
Am very much confused please any help?

Answer (score 0):

How much did you pay in fees? when they are too low they do take a while to confirm.

Keep in mind that you will not lose your coins. The tx will either get confirmed or around 48 hours that it hasn't been confirmed it will be invalidated (your coins returning to you).

Some wallets signal that a utxo is only spent after a transaction using it has been broadcast and confirmed. As you don't have confirmations, that's probably why it is marked as Unspent